# How do I loop over a JSON array with handlebars.js in a Shopify store?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, shopify, liquid

I'm making a GET request to `/cart.js`. It returns the following JSON data:

```
{
   "token":"118aa66ff7cc99c7fb4524f07bd305a4",
   "note":null,
   "attributes":{

   },
   "total_price":771,
   "total_weight":0,
   "item_count":3,
   "items":[
      {
         "id":903858951,
         "title":"Aarts Frambozen op siroop",
         "price":211,
         "line_price":211,
         "quantity":1,
         "sku":"wi195688",
         "grams":0,
         "vendor":"Aarts",
         "properties":null,
         "product_id":385866167,
         "variant_id":903858951,
         "gift_card":false,
         "url":"/products/aarts-frambozen-op-siroop?variant=903858951",
         "image":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0656/8697/products/AHI_434d50303234343731_dRevLabel_1_Rendition_LowRes_JPG.jpeg?v=1413443204",
         "handle":"aarts-frambozen-op-siroop",
         "requires_shipping":true
      },
      {
         "id":903852739,
         "title":"AH Aardappelschijfjes spek en ui",
         "price":211,
         "line_price":211,
         "quantity":1,
         "sku":"wi202676",
         "grams":0,
         "vendor":"AH",
         "properties":null,
         "product_id":385862935,
         "variant_id":903852739,
         "gift_card":false,
         "url":"/products/ah-aardappelschijfjes-spek-en-ui?variant=903852739",
         "image":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0656/8697/products/AHI_434d50303038363632_dRevLabel_2_Rendition_LowRes_JPG.jpeg?v=1413442904",
         "handle":"ah-aardappelschijfjes-spek-en-ui",
         "requires_shipping":true
      },
      {
         "id":903852571,
         "title":"AH Aardappelen iets kruimig voordeelzak",
         "price":349,
         "line_price":349,
         "quantity":1,
         "sku":"wi127728",
         "grams":0,
         "vendor":"AH",
         "properties":null,
         "product_id":385862819,
         "variant_id":903852571,
         "gift_card":false,
         "url":"/products/ah-aardappelen-iets-kruimig-voordeelzak?variant=903852571",
         "image":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0656/8697/products/AHI_434d50303233343335_dRevLabel_1_Rendition_LowRes_JPG.jpeg?v=1413442897",
         "handle":"ah-aardappelen-iets-kruimig-voordeelzak",
         "requires_shipping":true
      }
   ],
   "requires_shipping":true
}
```

What I'd like to do is iterator over the `items` and show the `id`, `title` and `quantity`.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<script class="foobar" charset="utf-8" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>
    {{#items}}
      <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{id}}</td>
          <td>{{title}}</td>
          <td>{{quantity}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    {{/items}}
  </div>
</script>

<script charset="utf-8">
  var source = $(".foobar").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

  var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "/cart.js", function() {
    console.log( "success" );
  })

  $('body').append(template(jqxhr.responseJSON));
</script>
```

But this returns:

```
Id Title Qty
```

Without any data. I know the GET request is working, because `console.log(jqxhr.responseJSON);` prints the correct data.

What am I doing wrong and what could I try next?

**Edit:**

I think I'm handling the Ajax response wrongly.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/narzero/4fn3f6sg

**Edit 2:**

It might be worth mentioning that I'm running the code on a Shopify store.

Comment: Use `{{#each items}} {{id}} {{/each}}`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h2qyh8f2/ is this something you'd like to do?

Comment: @DennisMartinez That's exactly what I want. But when I use that with the real JSON data it doesn't work. I think I'm handling the json response wrongly. Take a look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/narzero/kgtLpe5g/

Comment: @narzero Ah! Yes sorry, I didn't even think to look at the ajax response. Since you're doing an asynchronous call, you'll have to put the body.append portion of your code inside of the getJSON complete method. Try that, and let me know what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding the tags `{% raw %}` `{% endraw %}` inside the handlebar script class, like so:

```
<script class="foobar" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {% raw %}
    <div>
        <thead>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#items}}
          <tr>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{title}}</td>
            <td>{{quantity}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        {{/items}}
    </div>
  {% endraw %}
</script>
```

When using `{% raw %}` it makes sure that no liquid will be parsed within these tags.

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're looping over the data you've provided should work, but I see a minor mistake with the ajax call which would in fact make you think you're code isn't working.

You have to return your results in the complete callback of your code since you're using ajax, and ajax is asynchronous.

```
$.getJSON( "/cart.js", function(data) {
    $('body').append(template(data));
});
```

I'm not sure if it was on purpose or not, but you're table is not complete.

```
<script class="foobar" charset="utf-8" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#items}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{id}}</td>
                    <td>{{title}}</td>
                    <td>{{quantity}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/items}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: @narzero From what I'm seeing, the ajax call is commented out. Was it moved to an external script?

Comment: No, I commented it out to test something else, sorry for that. You can check it out. All the Ajax calls for the theme are in here: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0656/8697/t/7/assets/ajaxify.js?6701. You might find something in there. `Shopify.getCart` on line 191 for example..

Comment: @narzero I'm not sure if you're utilizing these methods (assumptions from your example given) but with the method getCart you could do `Shopify.getCart(function(cart) { $('body').append(template(cart)); });`

Comment: I was not utilising them, thanks for the info. If you visit the homepage, and copy paste that code into the console, does it work for you? The results should be at the bottom. It doesn't work for me. I get the table headers, but no data.